# Prevent Spring Batch automatic job trigger after context creation without Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-annotations, spring-config

I am setting up a project with **Spring Batch without using Spring Boot**.
When the Spring application context is created, all the jobs get executed.

I tried adding `spring.batch.job.enbled=false` to the *application.properties* to prevent this but it still does not work.

Is there any other way to stop Spring from executing the jobs at start?

Main Class:

```
package com.project.batch;
import ...    

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class App {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        System.out.println("starting main");

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.project.batch");
        context.refresh();

        //JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters();
        //JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        //JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(context.getBean("loaderJob",Job.class),jobParameters);
        System.out.println("finished!!");
    }
}
```

Job Class:

```
package com.project.batch;
import ... 

@Configuration
public class LoaderJobConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job loaderJob(Step step1) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting loaderJob");
        ...
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.batch.job.enbled=false
spring.batch.job.names=
```

Run logs:

```
starting main
Nov 06, 2017 9:29:02 AM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@306a30c7: startup date [Mon Nov 06 09:29:02 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 06, 2017 9:29:03 AM org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer intercept
WARNING: @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean Javadoc for complete details
Nov 06, 2017 9:29:03 AM org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer intercept
WARNING: @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean Javadoc for complete details
Nov 06, 2017 9:29:03 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver
Starting loaderJob
found the value: [MER]
Completed loaderJob
finished!!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

EDIT: Removed the job execution code from main class, the jobs still get triggered at context refresh

EDIT 2: Including run logs

EDIT 3: Fixed typo and updated logs

Comment: Your main method is executing the job.  Remove the code there if you don’t want I‎t to execute on startup...

Comment: @MichaelMinella I've removed the job execution code but the jobs still get triggered

Comment: Can you provide the logs showing the start?

Comment: Added the logs now

Comment: you have a typo in your properties: it should read `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`, not `enbled`

Comment: @dube updated the config but the job still gets executed

Answer (score 30):

The solution mentioned in Spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.html) worked for me.  I just added one line in application.properties and it stops the batch job execution on startup.

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

spring.batch.job.enabled=false

this configuration is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As per the Spring docs, adding below line to application.properties works fine for me:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```